# Quick question regarding alternative solutions to Natural deduction problem

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

Could someone verify that the following alternative attempts are both correct in the proof of the problem?

> $$\{P \lor \neg Q  , R \rightarrow \neg P \} \vdash Q \rightarrow \neg R  $$

**Attempt:**

$$\cfrac{\cfrac{format}{P \lor \neg Q} \qquad \cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{[R] \quad R \rightarrow \neg P}{\neg P} \qquad \cfrac{format}{[P]}}{\neg R}}{Q \rightarrow \neg R} \qquad \cfrac{\cfrac{[Q] \quad [\neg Q]}{\neg R}}{Q \rightarrow \neg R}}{Q \rightarrow \neg R}$$

**Alternative attempt:**
$$\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{format}{P \lor \neg Q} \qquad {\cfrac{\cfrac{format}{[P]} \quad \cfrac{[R] \quad R \rightarrow \neg P}{\neg P}}{\neg R}} \qquad \cfrac{[Q] \quad [ \neg Q]}{\neg R}}{\neg R}}{Q \rightarrow \neg R}$$

I had to add the word 'format' in the 'fractions' because i could not get the formatting to display correctly,sorry.I know the first attempt is correct and i was wondering if the alternative is correct too.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In what way does it not display correctly? Simply deleting "format" from the LaTeX produces a reasonable display for me. In particular, it looks basically identical except that the bars above $[P]$ are not as wide (since they don't need to stretch to contain "format").

Comment: Your attempt are essentially correct. Just a clarification: which rules do you use for negation introduction and elimination? You seem to use them in a non-uniform way.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.On my display, if i do not add something to the 'fraction',in my case it is the word 'format', the sentence in the denominator is too high..so i am 'pushing it down :-). I do not understand what you mean @Taroccoesbrocco, just the oridinary ones...i think?

Comment: Use `\lower{1.5ex}{P\lor Q}` to have the statement lowered to the same level as the denominator of the fractions. @HalfAFoot

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have any statements with a blank line over them, like $$\dfrac{}{P \lor \lnot Q}$$ Every line represents an invocation of a rule of inference, and there is no general rule of inference to infer $P \lor \lnot Q$.  It is just an assumption.  Instead it should just be

$$\dfrac{[P \lor \lnot Q] \qquad \dots}{\dots}$$

Same for the other blank lines.  Otherwise both proofs are correct.

---

Just to be clear, it is sometimes appropriate to have blank lines.  For example, if you have "the law of the excluded middle", then it would be appropriate to have

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{}{Z \lor \lnot Z} \qquad \dots}{\dots}$$

Because $Z \lor \lnot Z$ is axiomatic, it isn't some arbitrary assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the rules of inference used to justify the derivations, and also make sure you have matched the schema for *your particular* proof system (there are many variations).

If your version of "disjunction elimination" requires conditionals, then your first attempt needs to deduce $P\to\lnot R$ and $\lnot Q\to\lnot R$; since you are eliminating $P\lor\lnot Q$, after all.   *Then* you eliminate the assumption of $Q$ with conditional introduction.

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{P\vee\lnot Q}\quad\dfrac{\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{[P]^3}\quad\dfrac{[R]^4\quad R\to\lnot P}{\lnot P}{\small\to\!\mathsf E}}{\lnot R}{\small\lnot\mathsf I^4}}{P\to\lnot R}{\small\to\!\!\mathsf I^3}\quad\dfrac{\dfrac{[\lnot Q]^2\quad [Q]^1}{\lnot R}{\small\lnot\mathsf E}}{\lnot Q\to\lnot R}{\small\to\!\mathsf I^2}}{\lnot R}{\small\vee\mathsf E}}{Q\to\lnot R}{\small\to\!\mathsf I^1}$$

---

**However**

I notice that you appear to be using a *variant of* the negation introduction and elimination rules which do not use the $\bot$ symbol; skipping out the explicit "these statements are a contradiction" step (more usually called negation elimination).   That version of negation elimination rule is basically *ex falso quodlibet*.
$$\dfrac{\phi\quad\lnot\phi\quad [\rho]^\bullet}{\lnot\rho}{\small\lnot\mathsf I^\bullet}\qquad\dfrac{\phi\quad\lnot\phi}{\psi}{\small\lnot\mathsf E}$$

If this *is intentional*, it is quite okay, and does admittedly save space, rather than:$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\phi\quad\lnot\phi}{\bot}{\small\lnot\mathsf E}\quad\lower{1.25ex}{[\rho]^\bullet}}{\lnot\rho}{\small\lnot\mathsf I^\bullet}\qquad\dfrac{\dfrac{\phi\quad\lnot\phi}{\bot}{\small\lnot\mathsf E}}{\psi}{\small\mathsf{EFQ}}$$

If so, this does suggest to me that your version of "disjunction elimination" would likewise also skip the conditional introduction step, and just require the subproofs to derive the same conclusion: $\lnot R$. That is, your second attempt.

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{P\vee\lnot Q}\quad\dfrac{\lower{1.5ex}{[P]^3}\quad\dfrac{[R]^4\quad R\to\lnot P}{\lnot P}{\small\to\!\mathsf E}}{\lnot R}{\small\lnot\mathsf I^4}\quad\dfrac{[\lnot Q]^2\quad [Q]^1}{\lnot R}{\small\lnot\mathsf E}}{\lnot R}{\small\vee\mathsf E^{2,3}}}{Q\to\lnot R}{\small\to\!\mathsf I^1}$$

Comment: my goodness......